# Can I put open source data on a public github repo?

Tags: uses-of-open-data, releasing-data, legal, git

I am using open-source data for a data sonification project and would like to put the data used for this project onto a public Github repo. Are there any legal issues with doing this? I am assuming not because it is open source but just wanted to make sure.

Comment: Consider to use https://zenodo.org/ or (better esp. for raster data) https://figshare.com/ - they also offer to generate a dataset DOI for you

Answer (score 1):

If you are generating the data then there is presumably no legal issue at all. Please add a license to the repo so that people know how they can (re)use the data and code!

If you are hosting data from somewhere else then it’s usually allowed via Fair Use. It’s important to state that you don’t own the data and to express how the owner has licensed it. The typical “worst case” is that the data owner sends GitHub a takedown notice. Without financial loss it’s hard to make a case for any further legal action.

(I am not a lawyer!)